# Use time field from influxdb in grafana single stat

Tags: influxdb, grafana

Is it possible to use the `time` field in a single stat panel in grafana?

I understand you cannot only query the time field in influxdb, but I can get the time of the stat I'm interested in like so:

```
select time, last(context_id) from "data_context"
```

And just need a way to show the `time` field from the execution of the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quiet often asked on stack overflow, but it is not possible at the moment. But there are open Feature requests for this on github:

- [[Feature request] Show timestamp on SingleStat #6710](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6710)
- [Showing time from InfluxDB query in Singlestat panel #2764](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/2764)