# Grafana InfluxDB SingleStat Date Calculation

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I would like one of my Grafana panels to be a single stat, which calculates the days since the date of the last record in my table. I have tried to get this to work but can't figure out how to do the calculation and have it show up as my stat. Is this possible?

Comment: In short it is not possible at the moment! see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40963901/5183341 Check out the linked github feature requests and maybe upvote them if you also want this feature to be implemented!